# About illegal path , get xml info

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having an issue trying to work with a xml file, I've read a few posts here and elsewhere but I can't solve problem in work,I have some question in C#, About illegal path , get xml info

Question 1:

System.ArgumentException:There are illegal characters in the path

```
string path = "D:\\temp\\"+bbb+".log";
```

I wnat to set path name with Parameters:

```
string bbb = t1.Attribute("name").ToString();
string path = "D:\\temp\\"+bbb+".log";
```

example `file1.log file2.log file3.log` ....

Question 2:

I use linq to get some information from xml 
I want to get "path" information, but I only get `path ="D:\example1.c"`
I want to get and show only `D:\example1.c`

Code:

```
    var path = from q in doc.Element("content").Element("aaainfo").Elements("setting")
                                    select q;

                        foreach (var onlypath in path)
                        {                         
                            string getpath = onlypath.Attribute("path").ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(getpath  + ""); 
            }
```

xml:

```
<aaainfo>
    <setting name="file1" path ="D:\example1.c" serializeAs="String">
      <add value="aaa" name="file11" />
      <add value="bbb" name="file12" />
      <value />
    </setting>
     </aaainfo>
```

Question 3:

I want to get number about name and value,and I have log file to record.
Now when I use "file22.c" to open C# file,but I only get name = 2 , can't get value nauber.
(I think it recorded as file1 information , It may problem about xml ?)

The correct number is name = 3, name = 2
I can't get any infrmation about "file2"

code:

```
   var path = from q in doc.Element("content").Element("aaainfo").Elements("setting")
                                    select q;

                        foreach (var onlypath in path)
                        {                         
                            string getpath = onlypath.Attribute("path").ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(getpath  + "");
                m  ++;

            }
```

xml

```
 <aaainfo>
    <setting name="file2" path ="D:\example2.c" serializeAs="String">
      <add value="aaa2" name1="file21.c" />
      <add value="bbb2" name1="file22.c" />
      <add value="ccc2" name1="file23.c" />
      <value />
    </setting>
     </aaainfo>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `XAttribute.ToString()` everywhere, you need to either get `XAttribute.Value` property or simply cast the `XAttribute` to `string` :

```
string bbb = (string)t1.Attribute("name");
.....
string getpath = (string)onlypath.Attribute("path")
```

Comment: about path have error about "The name 'onlypath' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `onlypath` line in this answer is sample for your "Question 2"

Comment: But has get "path ="D:\example1.c" not "D:\example1.c"

Comment: That's because you were using `.ToString()`, try the way shown in this answer, have you?